# Why can't I add an observer to this Observable?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

The following is my code, that I followed along [this](https://medium.com/3xplore/handling-api-calls-using-retrofit-2-and-rxjava-2-1871c891b6ae) article:

```java
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/";
    public static final String ENDPOINT = "/v2/top-headlines";
    public static final String KEY = "my_key";
    public static final String C_CODE = "us";
    // main API ="https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=my_key

   public interface ResponseClient {
        @GET(ENDPOINT)
        Observable<MResponse> getArticles(@Query("apiKey") String key, @Query("country") String countryCode);

    }
    public static Observable<MResponse> loadDataViaRetroFit() {
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
        MoshiConverterFactory pojoConvertorMoshi = MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient= new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        Retrofit retrofit =
                new Retrofit.Builder().client(okHttpClient).baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(pojoConvertorMoshi)
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .build();

        ResponseClient client = retrofit.create(ResponseClient.class);

        Observable<MResponse> myObservable  = client.getArticles(KEY,C_CODE);

        return myObservable;

    }
```

According to that article, I should have been able to call this function  and register an observer for observing changes for my activity, but this is not being shown as an option.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What's more confusing is that why should I be the one providing the `MResponse`?

`MResponse` is the [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) class for the response that would be used by retrofit for auto-conversion of the JSON response, and I want to observe for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported the wrong `Observable` class.  You've imported [`android.database.Observable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Observable) instead of [`io.reactivex.Observable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html).  Switching the import should fix it.